# Possible mem leak?

Tags: c++, oop, visual-c++

I'm new to the concept so don't be hard on me.
why doesn't this code produce a destructor call ?
The names of the classes are self-explanatory.
The SString will print a message in ~SString().
It only prints one destructor message.

```
int main(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
smart_ptr<SString> smt(new SString("not lost"));
 new smart_ptr<SString>(new SString("but lost")); 
return 0;
}
```

Is this a memory leak? 
The impl. for smart_ptr is from  [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2997/A-generic-C-template-class-to-implement-a-smart-po)

**edited:**

```
//copy ctor
    smart_ptr(const smart_ptr<T>& ptrCopy) 
    {
        m_AutoPtr = new T(ptrCopy.get());
    }
    //overloading = operator
    smart_ptr<T>& operator=(smart_ptr<T>& ptrCopy) 
    {
        if(m_AutoPtr)
            delete m_AutoPtr;
        m_AutoPtr = new T(*ptrCopy.get());
        return *this;
    }
```

Comment: What is `new`'d, must be `delete`'d.

Comment: the dynamic memory is getting stored nowhere...!!!

Comment: Whatever you do, don't use that implementation for anything other than a learning exercise. Even after correcting the obsolete header names and fixing the obvious errors, its copy semantics are hopelessly broken. Use `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` in real code.

Comment: I've noticed that it's copy semantics are broken, but what if I change them in the following way, would that suffice for using in a production environment? or where can I find a complete and correct implementation?

Comment: @LCDFire: You'll need `delete` rather than `free`, and copying will be `new T(*ptrCopy)` after checking for null, and you'll slice the object if it's actually a subtype of `T`. It's rather tricky to get a smart pointer to correctly copy its target, which is why the standard library only provides a non-copyable `unique_ptr` and a reference-counting `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By `new smart_ptr<SString>(new SString("but lost"));` you are creating a new, dynamically allocated smart pointer. You don't store the result of the allocation (a pointer to a `shared_ptr` to a `SString`) anywhere, it's dangling... since you don't store the result, you also can not call `delete` for it - therefore it's destructor won't be called, and in turn also the `SString` destructor of the contained object won't be called!

If you try

```
smart_ptr<SString> *p = new smart_ptr<SString>(new SString("but lost")); 
delete p;
```

instead, you will see the destructor called also for this case.

However, that's no sensible use of a `smart_ptr`. `smart_ptr` were created so that you **don't** need to call `delete` manually; therefore, don't use them that way; use them as in your first statement!

Answer (score 8):

The point of a smart pointer is that you're supposed to have only *automatic* smart pointer objects:

```
{
    smart_ptr<Foo> p(new Foo);
}
// bye bye Foo
```

Your second line, however, creates a *dynamic* smart pointer, whose life never ends! Thus it never gets a chance to destroy the object it's in charge of.

You would have to delete the smart pointer itself manually, so that it can in turn clean up the object:

```
auto sp = new smart_ptr<Foo>(new Foo);
//                           ^^^^^^^
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^           +------< dynamic Foo, handled by the SP
//                     |
//                     +---------------< dynamic smart pointer, handled by YOU

delete sp;
```

Comment: "You would have to delete the smart pointer itself manually" - or put it in a smart... oh, never mind ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the smart point itself is leaked. (And anything it holds a reference to).

I cannot think of a good reason to `new` a smart pointer...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is a memory leak, you're leaking the second smart pointer and its contents.

The reason is that the first smart pointer is created on the stack, so its life-time is scoped to the block it is declared in, after that it will be automatically destroyed.

The second one is created on the heap, which means it will live until you destroy it with `delete` at which point its destructor will be called (and with that the destructor of the `SString` it is holding).